# idxmin return a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series called min_time_diff which has time differences calculated.Now I want to calculate the row where the time difference is minimum so 
I did `df3.loc[min_time_diff.idxmin()].`
But I just want to return a particular column from the row which is called 'Date'.Is that possible?

Comment: you mean like this `df3.loc[min_time_diff.idxmin()]['Date']` ?

Comment: Can you come up with a [MCVE] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a scalar, use [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) with scalar inputs:

```
df3.at[min_time_diff.idxmin(), 'Date']
```

If you need a series, use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a list row indexer:

```
df3.loc[[min_time_diff.idxmin()], 'Date']
```

Here's a demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

print(df.at[df['col1'].idxmin(), 'col2'])
1

print(df.loc[[df['col1'].idxmin()], 'col2'])
0    1
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```